# How to do a Drop down list in ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, xml, dropdown

I use SharePoint Online and Visual Studio 2013 and have created a Ribbon Custom Action.

How do make it into a ribbon dropdown list? Would be helpful if you can post things that I can use in my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <CustomAction Id="24013ac1-273d-49d9-bf3c-5db9f1c703c9.RibbonDD"
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="100"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
            Sequence="10001"
            Title="Invoke &apos;RibbonDD&apos; action">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <!-- 
  Update the UI definitions below with the controls and the command actions
  that you want to enable for the custom action.
  -->
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.RibbonDDButton"
              Alt="Request RibbonDD"
              Sequence="100"
              Command="Invoke_RibbonDDButtonRequest"
              LabelText="Request RibbonDD"
              TemplateAlias="o1"
              Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
              Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonDDButtonRequest"
                      CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension >
```

Comment: Will recommend you to look at Chris O'Brien log. A wonderful post, may that help you.
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/02/ribbon-customizations-dropdown-controls.html

Comment: I have looked at it but didn't get it to work